# Return results only where minimum date on a field

Tags: sql

I have a query that pulls user id and various events associated with each user. Since a user can have multiple events, I need the first event ever associated with each user.
Add a constraint to any answers - our server is delicate and has a hard time handling subqueries.

Here is the initial query:

```
  select 
        c.id as eid,
        c.created as contact_created,
        e.event_time,
        cs.name as initial_event_type
    from bm_emails.cid378 c
    inner join bm_sets.event378 e on e.eid = c.id
    inner join bm_config.classes cs on cs.id = e.class_id
    group by
        eid, initial_class
    order by eid desc
```

Which produces results that look like this:

```
eid     contact_created     event_time          initial_event_type
283916  2015-03-09 10:56:22 2015-03-09 10:57:21 Hot
283916  2015-03-09 10:56:22 2015-03-09 10:56:22 Warm
283914  2015-03-09 10:17:32 2015-03-09 10:17:32 Warm
283912  2015-03-09 10:11:03 2015-03-09 10:11:03 Warm
283910  2015-03-09 09:54:15 2015-03-09 09:54:15 Hot
```

So in this case user 283916 has been returned twice in the results. What I'd like is to return only one result for this user, the one where initial_event_type says "warm" since that happened first (min event_time).

Here is what I tied. Presumably it would work on  a more powerful server but ours just can't handle sub queries - it takes a long time and our developer gets upset whenever I leave queries running.

```
select 
    c.id as eid,
    c.created as contact_created,
    e.event_time,
    cs.name as initial_class
from bm_emails.cid378 c
inner join bm_sets.event378 e on e.eid = c.id
inner join bm_config.classes cs on cs.id = e.class_id
where concat(e.eid, e.event_time) in (  select concat(eid, min(event_time)) 
                                        from bm_sets.event378
                                        group by eid)
group by
    eid, initial_class
order by eid desc
```

Is it possible to pull this data without use of sub queries? I've seen people do multiple joins on the same table before and I think that may be the right path but, like our server, my brain is not powerful enough to figure out how to start on that path.

Any other more efficient solutions?

** Following answer by below, here is outcome of explain statement:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pull this data without use of sub queries

The fact that you use a subquery is not the problem.  The problem is cause by filtering on `concat(eid, min(event_time)` in your subquery since there is likely not an index on this expression, requiring a table scan.  A better option would be a *filtered* subquery:

```
select 
    c.id as eid,
    c.created as contact_created,
    e.event_time,
    cs.name as initial_class
from bm_emails.cid378 c
inner join bm_sets.event378 e on e.eid = c.id
inner join bm_config.classes cs on cs.id = e.class_id
where e.event_time = (  select min(event_time) 
                                        from bm_sets.event378
                                        WHERE eid = e.eid))
order by eid desc
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. The query seems to be struggling though. I'm sure it's more efficient than is was before nonetheless but I'm wondering if there's any more I can do to tighten it up? I'll paste a screen shot of the outcome of "explain" in my question in case that offers any pointers.

Comment: The first step in improving query performance is using indexes.  Is there an index on `eid` and `event_time` in `event378`?  The ideal index for this query would be a compound index on `eid` and `event_time`).  You should also look at the execution plan and see where the majority of the time is being spent (this usually requires a competent DBA, which I am not).

Comment: In this instance I have noticed that contact_created date corresponds to the earliest event_time so I joined them. Accepting because I'm sure this works faster than my original query. Thanks